# Can someone please help with Electronics transient/capacitor question?

Tags: capacitor

Can someone please help with Electronics transient capacitor question ?

The answer I keep getting is a minus so I think obviously I am wrong.

This question is in this link

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/78735682@N06/7210829818/]

from my class notes the only information I have to answer the question is

\$\cfrac{V}{2}\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\right)\$

tau = 3R/2 (c)

c = 2x1x0.001 / 3xRxLog(0.9)

Comment: Thanks for attempting the question!  What steps bring you to a negative result? (the correct steps won't, so we need to know what you're doing differently).  Also, leaving the question in a linked image is rather counterproductive, others can't search for it and it's difficult to read.  Please edit your question so that the question is in text (it's not that hard to retype!).

Comment: It would also be good if you could put some effort into formatting your equations.  We use [MathJax](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) here, I'm guessing that your first equation should be something more like `\$\cfrac{V}{2}\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\right)\$` and I've edited it to reflect this but you should check this and do the others.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that you assume that the voltage after the switch, \$V_1\$ is \$\dfrac{V}{2}\$. That will indeed be the case in steady state, when the capacitor is fully charged. But that voltage varies! At the moment the switch closes the capacitor's \$R\$ and the right \$R\$ are parallel, so then

\$ V_1 = \dfrac{R||R}{R||R + R}V = \dfrac{1}{3}V \$

Write down the three currents as a function of \$V_1\$, and since you know \$I_1\$ = \$I_2\$ + \$I_3\$ you should be able to find an equation for \$V_1\$.

Note that since \$V_1\$ isn't constant you can't use the exponential curve for the capacitor's voltage. You'll have to write out a new integral.

Comment: @stevenhv You can use the exponential curve, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#DC_circuits) points out the math. Check my anwser and ask for clearifaction, if needed. Besides that, which currents are $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$ and which voltages are $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$ exactly?

Comment: @suha - no, you can't. The exponential is only valid when you have a constant voltage source charging the capacitor. Here the voltage varies with the charging current and the capacitor's voltage.

Comment: @stevenvh The source labeled V is the schematic symbol for a single-cell battery. This in turn can be seen as a constant voltage source, right? Besides that there are only resistors and the one capacitor in the circuit, so no other (variable) voltage source. To sum it up: We have just one constant voltage source, which charges the capacitor. The remaining resistors can be incorporated into the voltage source using [Thévenin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem).

Answer (score -1):

I did not sat down with pen and paper, but your formula seems to describe $$V_C(t)$$ with $$\tau = \frac{3R}{2C}$$. $$V_C$$ and $$R$$ give you $$I(t)$$. You can calculate $$I(t=1\mu s)$$ and solve $$0.9*I(t=1\mu s) = V_C$$ for $$C$$ afterwards. Throw some Ohms Law in the mix and you are done. I hope that helps.

Comment: You simply repeat what OP mentions in the question. Which he says he knows is wrong. stevenvh hints at the source of the error.

Comment: He says the only information he has are the formulas and he asks for help. If you sit down and do the math, you will see that it is correct. stephenvh correctly points out the wrong steady state assumption, but the formula obviously describes the *transient* state (hence t for time and $$\tau$$ as the time constant). Simple Laplace-transformation does it.

Comment: @FedericoRusso just for myself for a better understanding: Have you ever dealt with Laplace-transformations and control theory? (no offense)